# Angular 4 not displaying data - simple example not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to show some data but Angular only displays empty bullet points. I get the error that says "Cannot read the property of 0 undefined". The code seems ok to me but is not working. What is wrong?

The code I have is:

**a) Offer.ts**

```
export class Offer
{
    constructor(
      public id      : number,
      public title   : string,
      public owner   : string,
      public productOffer    : [ {'id': number, 'name': string} ]) {}
}
```

**b) offer.component.ts**

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Offer } from '/offer';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser"; 

 @Component({
  selector   : 'app-offers',
  templateUrl: './offers.html',
  styleUrls  : ['./offers.scss']
            })  

export class OffersComponent implements OnInit {
 public offers: Offer[];
  constructor() { 
    this.offers = [
      {
        id : 1,
        title : 'Offer 01',
        owner : 'Mr Owner',
        productOffer : [                                                 
           { id : 1, name: 'Soap'},
           { id : 2, name: 'Cover'},
                  ]
      },
      {
        id : 2,
        title : 'Offer 01',
        owner : 'Mr Owner2',
        productOffer : [                                                 
           { id : 1, name: 'Soap2'},
           { id : 2, name: 'Cover2'},
                  ]
              }];               
          }

         ngOnInit() {  } 

        }
```

**c) offer.component.html**

```
<ul ng-repeat="offer in offers">
        <li>example</li>
        <li><h1>{{ offer.owner }}</h1></li>
        <li>{{offer.title}}</li><br><br>
        <li><button>{{offer.id}}</button></li>
</ul>
```

**d) I have also tried:**

```
  <ul>
    <li>example</li>
    <li *ngFor="let offer of offers">{{ offer.owner }}</li>     
  </ul>
```

The output I am getting with both is:

[image]

And this error:

[image]

Thanks for any help. I have been hours trying to fix it but I do not understand why is not working.

Comment: your code and question are quite mixed up.  you have tagged [tag:angularjs] and are using `ng-repeat`, which are definitely angular 1.x.  however, your js is importing `@angular/core`, which is absolutely angular 2.x .  These frameworks are not the same, and are essentially 3rd cousins.  You can't mix the two syntax under normal circumstances.  of course someone else changed the tag, but you still have `ng-repeat` in the code.

Comment: This is in angular 4 correct? If so replace the `ng-repeat` to `*ngFor`.

Comment: the second code snippet won't work with the code you have supplied here, since you don't seem to have a `tenders` array defined anywhere.

Comment: also, this line seems erronious:  `import { Tender } from '/offer';`

Comment: all in all, there is enough wrong here that a [mcve] is really needed to correct all the issues.  I've been trying to recreate the code and correct issues as I encounter them, but still not really getting the result you are showing here.

Comment: Sorry, those errors are because I changed the names to avoid using my real data. I will fix that detail as well.

Comment: are you getting your offers contents via http?

Comment: No, I am trying to get the contents from offer.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `*ngFor` instead of `ng-repeat` because your code is written in *Angular*, not in *AngularJS*. Also Instead of `in` you need to use `of`.

```
<ul *ngFor="let offer of offers">
     <li>example</li>
     <li><h1>{{ offer.owner }}</h1></li>
     <li>{{ offer.title }}</li><br><br>
     <li><button>{{ offer.id }}</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixed AngularJS with Angular(since version 2, and now it is version 5.2):
The syntax for each is:

```
<!-- AngularJS -->
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{$index}} {{item}}
  </li>
</ul> 

<!-- Angular -->
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    {{i}} {{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```